# Why did Tywin enter the court on a Stallion?

Tags: character, analysis, game-of-thrones

This is about *Game of Thrones* S2 finale episode "Valar Morghulis". In the scene where Tywin Lannister is named as the the "Hand of the King" and the "Saviour of the city" by Joffrey Baratheon, Tywin Lannister enters the King's court on his stallion rather than by walk. Not to forget, his horse s*its just before entering the throne room.

What is the significance of him entering the court room on a stallion and not on foot? What does the horse s*it add to the scene?

Comment: Fun fact, in the books, the horse unloads right in front of the throne.

Comment: `The Lord of Casterly Rock made such an impressive figure that it was a shock when his destrier dropped a load of dung right at the base of the throne. Joffrey had to step gingerly around it as he descended to embrace his grandfather and proclaim him Savior of the City.`

Comment: Cross Site Dupe: [Why did Tywin ride a horse into the courtroom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64162/why-did-tywin-ride-a-horse-into-court)?

Comment: It also looks really badass!

Answer (score 8):

**Why did Tywin enter the court on a Stallion?**

Because he can. Believe it or not Tywin was the indirect king at that time. He was able to make Tyrion hand of king without consulting the council, Cersei or even the king earlier and then break all his dream when he takes over the position. That seems like his way of showing off his power over throne. Like his way of saying "he doesn't give a shit"

**What does the horse defecation add to the scene?**

Foreshadowing I guess, rest will be spoiler for you regarding the future of Tywin:

> When Tywin got killed by Tyrion using the crossbow, he was defecating at the time.

Comment: "Because he can" is the right answer. Not sure about the foreshadowing part. I don't believe it is anything deeper or has a meaning other than just cementing Tywin's "Cus I can" vibe

Comment: Also as fancy as horses seem, they do just drop a deuce whenever.

Comment: I don't quite agree with the foreshadowing link. It seems a more direct reference on how Tywin does not view himself as an underling of the Iron Throne, but rather in a position where he literally gets to shit on it with no further consequence. While the shitting was likely not planned by Tywin, he also makes no effort to apologize or feel like he was in the wrong, which reveals his true feelings about his relationship with the Iron Throne.